# Upgrading Java and Setting as Default on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, minecraft

I'm new to Raspberry-Pi & Linux and I wanted to code up a Minecraft server using PaperMC, but when I ran the server I got a warning saying that Java-11 would no longer be supported in future builds, so I thought it would be easy enough to upgrade to Java-16. I have not found documentation regarding this topic specifically which has led to using parts of differing tutorials, and I think I made a few mistakes. To start, I purged the old Java-11 version like so:

```
sudo -i 
apt-get purge openjdk*
apt-get purge java11*
apt-get autoremove
```

Then I moved to the jvm directory and installed Java-16 from AdpotOpenJDK:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
wget https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk16-binaries/releases/download/jdk-16.0.1%2B9/OpenJDK16U-jre_aarch64_linux_hotspot_16.0.1_9.tar.gz
tar xzf OpenJDK16U-jre_aarch64_linux_hotspot_16.0.1_9.tar.gz
export PATH=$PWD/jdk-16.0.1+9-jre/bin:$PATH
java -version
openjdk version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-16.0.1+9 (build 16.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

This export PATH command seems to be temporary, when I logout of sudo or exit the command window, and then check java -version again I get that the java command is not found. If I try setting JAVA_HOME & PATH:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-16.0.1+9-jre"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

The result is also temporary. Why can't I set this Java-16 as the default? Do I need to make a script that runs these commands on startup?

Comment: I’m surprised to hear of some project planning to drop support for Java 11. Java 8 and 11 are the only Long-Term Support (LTS) releases. Java 16 will be supported only several months. Java 17 this autumn might be another LTS, but that is not certain. Can you add a link to your project’s statement, out of curiosity?

Comment: So I had to re-download Java-11 and run the server again, unfortunately the warning is too long but here is the link from it: https://papermc.io/java16. Also, here is the tutorial link that I am using to make the server: https://www.linuxnorth.org/minecraft. I guess default java doesn't exist anymore thanks to whatever I did b/c I had to use the export PATH command to set Java-11 in order to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to install it permanently using apt. Link to the information
https://paper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/java-update/index.html#debian-ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install apt-transport-https software-properties-common gnupg wget
$ wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo add-apt-repository https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install adoptopenjdk-16-hotspot
```

Comment: Doesn’t work for Raspbian. 
`could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/buster`